# Getting wrong value of Time in Google Calendar

Tags: c#, datetime, google-calendar-api

I am migrating Calendars to Google Apps using Google API Version 2 for .NET as below:

```
EventEntry entry    = new EventEntry();
entry.Title.Text    = "Test Calendar";
When   eventTime    = new When(StartDate, EndDate, false);
```

I am setting : :
StartDate = {6/18/2010 3:00:00 PM}
EndDate   = {6/18/2010 4:00:00 PM}

But after migration it is setting Calendar Date and Time as:

StartDate = 6/18/2010 9:30am
EndDate   = 6/18/2010 10:30am

I tried with changing my Calendar Time Zone value to 
"(GMT + 00:00) GMT (no daylight saving)" also.But issue remain same.

How to resolve this issue?

Thanx

Answer (score 0):

What are you expecting your "3 pm" to be? UTC or local?

I admit I don't know what the Google Calendar API expects or will convert it to - but I would suggest you try specifying the UTC time of the event.

Did your previous code work in v1? Do you have a sample program which can easily be toggled between v1 and v2, showing them behaving differently? (If you can create such a program, I can try to get to the bottom of it internally.)

Comment: I want to set Time to Local.
I never used V1.How can i specify time zone here?

Comment: @Preeti: You don't specify the time zone for a one-off event - it only makes sense for a recurrent event. However, if you want your DateTime to be viewed as local for the purposes of specifying the one-off time of this event, specify `DateTimeKind.Local` in the constructor to `DateTime`. At least give it a try :)